# WindowsPhone 8 persistent AdControl

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, ads

I am looking to making a multi-paged WindowsPhone 8 app that features an `AdControl` at the bottom. Now what I am interested in is to find out if there's a possibility of putting the AdControl in a separate frame of sorts so that the page navigation doesn't interfere with it. Basically I'm trying to split the app `ViewPort` into 2 parts: the app and the AdControl.

The AdControl should always be on and there would be no need to add it to different pages and to refresh it each time a navigation is performed.

Can something like this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this by setting the style of the PhoneApplicationFrame. In the App.xaml, add the following resource

```
<Style x:Key="AdPhoneApplicationFrameStyle" TargetType="phone:PhoneApplicationFrame">
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="phone:PhoneApplicationFrame">
                <Border x:Name="ClientArea" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                            <adDuplex:AdControl Grid.Row="1"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

In App.xaml.cs within the `InitializePhoneApplication` add the following line after the RootFrame is created

```
RootFrame.Style = (Style)Resources["AdPhoneApplicationFrameStyle"];
```

If you want to have page transitions, see this [blog post](http://www.visuallylocated.com/post/2014/02/21/Add-a-persistent-element-to-your-phone-apps.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for helping me out. I used your code inside a blank phone app and modified from `<adDuplex:AdControl Grid.Row="1"/>` `<UI:AdControl Grid.Row="1" ApplicationId="test_client" AdUnitId="Image480_80"/>`, referenced etc. The problem I'm having right now is that apparently the frame is on top of everything and thus I cannot click buttons I got in MainPage.xaml. Also the ad isn't show, but I can now see the border (modified it slightly to be red) which occupies the whole screen (so I guess the ad is just blow that outside of the screen)

Comment: Okey I kinda solved that problem by...removing the border ^^. Now I have to figure out how to make the `adControl` to be shown inside the viewport.

Comment: Solved it. Thank you very much for the solution!